# Is there an olfactory equivalent expression to "the scenic route"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

"Taking the scenic route" implies taking a less direct alternative to the most direct route toward some destination for the purpose of experiencing more interesting scenery along the way. So, is there an expression, phrase, or idiom that basically means the same thing for smells?

For example, when I walk my dog in the park, I let him choose the route we take.  As such, our route through the park will often make erratic turns and circle back on itself in a path generally determined by his nose, i.e. by the direction toward the most interesting (to him) smells each instant.

If I were to be asked later to describe where our walk in the park went, I could euphemistically say, "we took the scenic route" through the park.  But that implies my dog was navigating by sight when in fact he was navigating by smell (he is almost blind). So is there an olfactory equivalent to "the scenic route" in a case like this, for smells?

"The smelly route" definitely has a negative connotation.
"The mellifluous route" or "The quiet route" might work for an auditory equivalent.  But what would be an olfactory equivalent?

Comment: The sniffy route?

Comment: The canine sommelier route.  [Sommelier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommelier).  A sommelier uses their nose as much as their taste buds.

Comment: The smelly route

Comment: If you like consonance,  "the redolent route" might work well.

Comment: How about "follow your nose"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the point of view of the dog, ***the scented route*** is appropriate.  **Scent**, from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scent):

> 1 : effluvia from a substance that affect the sense of smell: such as 
>   a : an odor left by an animal on a surface passed over
>
> b : a characteristic or particular odor   especially : one that is
>   agreeable.

**The scented route** also means that the dog is tracking the routes of other dogs and other animals. Dogs have been used for millennia to catch and follow the scent of an animal that is being hunted.  Dogs now are specially trained to find a missing person, or to search for drugs in luggage at airports, or to find cadavers in places like Ground Zero. Some dogs are even being trained to detect the characteristic scents of various cancers.

The dog follows the odors on the scented route with enthusiasm, so we can safely infer that the scents are interesting, and probably pleasant, to the dog.  In his turn, the dogs marks a tree or a hydrant, saying:

> "Hi, I've been here".

However, From the point of view of you, or another person walking a dog, ***the odiferous route*** might be more appropriate, because, many of the things the dog is smelling with enjoyment would be repugnant to you.  Odiferous, from [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/odoriferous):

> Having or giving off an odor, especially a strong or unpleasant one:
>   an odoriferous bag of garbage.

There may not be a word that perfectly captures both the dog's experience and yours on the same route, but **the scented route** comes close; you just find the scents disagreeable if you can smell them at all.

Comment: Shame _scentic_ isn’t really a word – it would be the perfect fit here.

Comment: I like the scented route because it alliterates well with the scenic route.  But I think odiferous is the word I couldn't pull out of my hat.

Answer (score 2):

Do you require something that specifically refers to *where*? 
A phrase that captures the meaning you seem to be looking for
is ***taking time to smell the roses***. 
It is typically used metaphorically / idiomatically:

> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stop_and_smell_the_roses):
>
>   stop and smell the roses
>     *(idiomatic)*
>     To relax; to take time out of one's busy schedule
>       to enjoy or appreciate the beauty of life.
>
> [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+and+smell+the+roses):
>
>   stop and smell the roses
>     To become calm
>       and reflect upon the finer or more enjoyable aspects of life,
>       especially when one has become overworked or overly stressed.
>     *You can't keep working these 80 hour workweeks, John! 
>       You have to stop and smell the roses,
>       or else what is all that work even for?*
>
> [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slow%20down%20and%20smell%20the%20roses):
>
>   slow down and smell the roses
>     this means stop stressing out, overthinking, or complaining. 
>       put your troubles in perspective
>       and try to enjoy the short time you have on earth.

but there's no reason why you couldn't use it literally
(or at least semi-literally).

TIL Ringo Starr sang a song called
"Stop And Take The Time To Smell The Roses"
([lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ringostarr/stopandtakethetimetosmelltheroses.html), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGgmA7tkDlY)). 
It's silly, and maybe a little subversive.

The phrase is also mentioned [here on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/86914/26083).

Answer (score -1):

The  'Via Effluvia' or the 'Fragrant Passage'?

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, adding published examples or definitions for your suggestions, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: Fragrant is another good "smell" word that wouldn't come out of my hat.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).